# Proper way to upgrade hard drive on Lenovo IdeaPad Z570 keeping the OEM Windows license

Tags: windows-7

I'd like to upgrade my Lenovo IdeaPad Z570 to have an SSD hard-drive.

It comes with OEM Windows 7 license (underneath it the license key is written, along with a note of "Windows 7 Home Prem OA").

I have a Windows 7 Home Premium DVD box that I used for my desktop system.

Can I just use those disks to install Windows 7 on the laptop's brand new SSD, and then use the license key written underneath the laptop to activate it? Or will I have to call Microsoft or do something else?

Are there any steps that I can take prior to installing the SSD to make this easier - e.g., deactivate the Windows on the old HDD somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the DVD that you brought for other system, though feasible, in some sense is an act of piracy. A more "proper" method is to use the notebook's recovery disc utility to create a recovery disc, hook your new harddisk drive up and do a full recovery with the disc that you have just created. More information of the tool can be retrieved at http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/product-and-parts/detail.page?&LegacyDocID=MIGR-4Q2QAK
Alternatively, you can use softwares to clone your current harddisk to your new SSD such as [EASEUS Partition Master](http://www.partition-tool.com/copy-wizard/upgrade-system-disk.htm).

Comment: I accepted the answer as you gave a good link about the recovery tool and also brought the cloning idea up. But I'm really not sure why using the other DVD would be piracy.

Answer (score 0):

Just take out your old hard drive and put in your new ssd. Then attempt to install windows using your DVD. If it is the correct disk your key will be valid and you will be able to activate windows. If not you can just not put in a key and get a month long "trial" of win7. If it is the right version of windows for the key though it will activate fine as it is the same mobo and cpu as when you have used that key before. If it all fails though you can ring microsoft and explain to them what you are doing or swap back to your old HD until you get it sorted. Good luck!